# Arcore: how did Google occlude the box's outside in their augmented images demo?

Tags: java, android, 3d, arcore

In this demo https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/
They are able to occlude the box so if appears flat but I cant find any documentation that explains this feature

Comment: When you talk about occluding "the box's outside" or "the box", do you mean occluding the black square?

Comment: I mean occluding the box so that if you look at from an angle you dont see the depth of the box at all, instead it looks like its built into the wall. Typically the 3d model is drawn over the camera output so you would see a floating box over the wall, and it would require manual work from both the developers and artists to get this effect

Comment: The effect is due to the accurate registration of the position of the painting/image as the painting/image itself is considered  "marker" or "indicia".  Vuforia has had image target examples for a few years now. Once you have a accurate spatial location of the target, usual 3D tricks of depth apply.